# Efficiently get subset of strings "startingWith" out of a set

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, substring, subset

I have a **big** set of strings and I want to create an autosuggest feature for it.

Assume the set is  `["foo", "fighter"]`

Typing `"f"` should return both values, and typing `"fo"` should only return `"foo"`.

Currently I am just iterating through the set and filering out results by calling `startsWith`, however it's too slow.

The standard `TreeSet` with its subset functions will not help much here as it only implements a RB tree.

Is there an efficient solution in the Java API or do I have to build my own `Set` implementation?

---

Edit:
My implementation looks like this, using Andrey Naumenkos [trie datastructures](https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo/trie). Notice to increase the array size if you want to use extended ASCII characters. If you use a `List` instead of the `Map` you get the results in a sorted order.

```
public Set<String> getSubset(String s) {
    result = new HashSet<String>();
    getSubset(root, s);
    return result;
}

private void getSubset(TrieNode node, String s) {
    TrieNode n = node;
    for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (n.children[ch] != null) {
            n = n.children[ch];
            continue;
        }
        return;
    }
    getSubsetR(n, s);
}

private void getSubsetR(TrieNode node, String s) {
    for (char ch = 0; ch < node.children.length; ch++) {
        TrieNode child = node.children[ch];
        if (child != null)
            getSubsetR(child, s + ch);
    }
    if (node.leaf) {
        result.add(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are looking for is a prefix tree data structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

The code here will get you started: https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo/trie

Comment: Apache commons implementation of a compresed trie: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html

Comment: Knew the datastructure but forgot the name. This was exactly what I was looking for. Working perfectly after minor changes. Thank you.